Error al dar un alta
Cuando quiero dar un alta de provincias da error:

Warning: Undefined variable $id_pais in C:\xampp\htdocs\GaiaSoft\provincias_altas.php on line 12


Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'id_pais' at row 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\GaiaSoft\provincias_altas.php:14 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\GaiaSoft\provincias_altas.php(14): mysqli_query(Object(mysqli), 'INSERT INTO pro...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\GaiaSoft\provincias_altas.php on line 14"

El código que escribí es el siguiente:
<?php 
    include('conexion.php');

    //error_reporting(0);
    

    if  ( ( isset($_POST['Alta'])) ) {

        //Carga de datos
        extract($_POST);

        $sql="INSERT INTO provincias (provincia, id_pais) VALUES ('$provincia', '$id_pais')";
        //$sql="INSERT INTO `gaiasoft`.`provincias` (`provincia`, `id_pais`) VALUES ('Barcelona', '9')";
        $result=mysqli_query($conexion, $sql); 
        
   }
?>



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Altas de Provincias</title>
    </head>

<body>  

    <?php
        $paises = 'select * from paises order by pais';
        $id_pais = $conexion->query($paises);
    ?>


    <form action="provincias_altas.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="provincias_altas">

        <label for="provincia">Provincia:</label><br>
        <input name="provincia" id="provincia" type="text" placeholder="Ingrese la provincia" required><br><br>
       
        <label for="pais">País:</label><br>
        <select name="id_pais" id="id_pais">
        <?php
          if ($id_pais->num_rows > 0) {
            // Mostrar los datos en el combo desplegable
            while($rowgpais = $id_pais->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo '<option value="' . $rowgpais["id"] . '">' . $rowgpais["pais"] . ' </option>';
            }
        } else {
            echo '<option value="">No hay opciones disponibles</option>';
        } ?>
        </select><br><br>

        <input type="submit" name="Alta" value="Guardar Provincia">

    </form>

    <br><br><br>
    <<?php 
        include("menu.php");
    ?>


</body>
</html>


Cuando ejecuté la sentencia: INSERT INTO gaiasoft.provincias (provincia, id_pais) VALUES ('Barcelona', '9')";  funcionó perfecto, evidentemente no me eestá reconociendo el id_pais.

Al enviar el formulario, los datos que contenía el mismo se encuentran dentro de la variable $_POST, en otras palabras, deberías recuperar id_pais y provincia del arreglo $_POST.

son los quirks de usar extract

Tal como indica @marcos, debes extraer en variables los datos que llegan en la super global $_POST.
Así por ejemplo:
if  ( isset($_POST['Alta']) ) {

    //Carga de datos
    $provincia = $_POST["provincia"];
    $id_pais = $_POST["id_pais"];

    $sql="INSERT INTO gaiasoft.provincias (provincia, id_pais) VALUES ('$provincia', '$id_pais')";
    //$sql="INSERT INTO `gaiasoft`.`provincias` (`provincia`, `id_pais`) VALUES ('Barcelona', '9')";
    $result=mysqli_query($conexion, $sql); 
       
}

Intenta de esta manera y realiza los ajustes necesarios para que coincida con tu proyecto y si tienes dudas adicionales, deja un comentario.
Y ten cuidado con la inyección SQL. Investiga un poco sobre las sentencias preparadas o prepared statements

La obtención de esos datos exponen el código a situaciones de Undefined index. Es mejor obtenerlos con un ternario o fusión de null, por ejemplo: $provincia=$_POST["provincia"] ?? null; y $id_pais = $_POST["id_pais"] ?? null;. Luego tienes que evaluar según la realidad de tus datos. Por ejemplo, si ambos valores tienen restricción NOT NULL en la tabla: if  ( isset($_POST['Alta']) && !is_null($provincia) && !is_null($id_pais) ) { //INSERT } else { //No se puede insertar nulos } Otra ventaja de fusión de null es que puedes también asignar un valor por defecto si fuera el caso.

Gracias, funcionó, veré de no usar más extract(POST)
